# How can I create table with headers on the left and multiple rows in it

Tags: css, vue.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a table which may have various number of columns (headers) and also various number of data in it. It is being populated using `v-for`. Sample code would be something like this:

```
     <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table">
            <thead><tr>
                <th v-for="header in table_headers">
                    <span>@{{header}}</span>
                </th>
            </tr></thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr v-for="body in table_body">
                    <td>
                       @{{body}}    
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Which creates table that looks like this:

```
+-------------+---------+---------+
|    Name     | Middle  | Surname |
+-------------+---------+---------+
| Christopher | Ashton  | Kutcher |
| William     | Bradley | Pitt    |
| Thomas      | Sean    | Connery |
+-------------+---------+---------+
```

How can I convert this into table which would have header in first column and all the data in second:

```
+---------+-------------+
| Name    | Christopher |
| Middle  | Ashton      |
| Surname | Kutcher     |
| ------- | ----------- |
| Name    | William     |
| Middle  | Bradley     |
| Surname | Pitt        |
| ------  | ----------- |
| Name    | Thomas      |
| Middle  | Sean        |
| Surname | Connery     |
+---------+-------------+
```

Data in JSON:

```
{
  "columns": {
    "0": "Name",
    "1": "Middle",
    "2": "Surname"
  }
}

{
  "data": {
    "Name": ["Christopher", "William", "Thomas"],
    "Middle": ["Ashton", "Bradley", "Sean"],
    "Surname": ["Kutcher", "Pitt", "Connery"]
  }
}
```

Comment: In a table, you cannot have `thead` left of `tbody`. If you only want to achieve the visual result you showed (and you don't care about semantic use of HTML), that's easy to do.

Comment: Yes, I only need visual result. Can you just give me some guidelines how to write it?

Comment: Post the data as JSON, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the following data:

```
data() { return {
  names: [ 
    { "Name": "Christopher", "Middle": "Ashton", "Surname": "Kutcher" },
    { "Name": "William", "Middle": "Bradley", "Surname": "Pitt" },
    { "Name": "Thomas", "Middle": "Sean", "Surname": "Connery" },
  ]
}
```

This would be your HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr v-for="name in names">
    <td>
      <div v-for="key in Object.keys(name)">{{ key }}</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div v-for="value in Object.values(name)">{{ value }}</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```js
let template = `<table>
  <tr v-for="name in names">
    <td>
      <div v-for="key in Object.keys(name)">{{ key }}</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div v-for="value in Object.values(name)">{{ value }}</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>`

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  template,
  data() { return {
      names: [ 
        { "Name": "Christopher", "Middle": "Ashton", "Surname": "Kutcher" },
        { "Name": "William", "Middle": "Bradley", "Surname": "Pitt" },
        { "Name": "Thomas", "Middle": "Sean", "Surname": "Connery" },
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Will try in a minute and then accept your answer. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to make those two columns same size? I have tried wrapping everything arround with `<div class="row">` and later added those two `<div>` tags inside `<td>` class: `<div class="row">`, but it didn't help, furthermore it force it to go `inline` instead of `block`.

Comment: `table { table-layout: fixed; } table td { width: 50%; }`

Comment: Wow, now that was pretty fast! Yes, that could be one solution, but I was told that I am not allowed to change `css` and that since on this project we are using bootstrap I should fix everything using it's classes. But thanks, if I don't find anything else, I'm gonna use this, who cares

Comment: @connexo How can I use this `template` syntax with `export default` way instead of `new Vue` ?